# How to make an auto-populated video gallery based on videos in a directory?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make an auto-generated table of videos based on video files in a directory hosted on the server.  I've attempted to do it with JQuery but from all that I've read and tested this won't work.  I can't seem to find the proper documentation on the subject, I can't use anything like NodeJS or ASP.net sadly.  the web server that I'm using doesn't support it.

I initially used ASP.net but as I previously mentioned my host provider doesn't accept the format.

```
<div class="browse"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var directory = 'videos/';
  var workspace = document.getElementsByClassName('browse');
  $.ajax({url: directory}).then(function(html){
    var document = $(html);

    document.find('a[href$=.mp4]').each(function(){
      var name = $(this).text();
      var url = $(this).attr('href');
      workspace.innerHTML = '<video alt="'+ name +'" src="'+ url +'"></video>';
    })
  });
</script>
```

I was hoping that it would create a video tag with the source the file in the directory.  but nothing happened.

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName I think returns a collection of elements, indexed beginning with [0].  That might be part of the problem.  What are you getting back from your ajax call in html ?  If you have multiple divs with class = browse, might be able to just alter your .each to include function(index) and then use "index" to index your collection of workspace elements, i.e. workspace[index].

Comment: You are going to need some sort of server-side language to get the information that you want. Maybe your ISP doesn't support ASP (Microsoft charges a far whack to use their server) but they might support php. Also, in your code you are using var document = $(html) - you are trashing the entire web page (document is a reserved word). Use another variable name.

Comment: @jeff Since it's inside a function, `var document = $(html)` only shadows the global variable within that scope; it's not "trashing" anything. Even so, it's still a poor choice for a variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to do this with PHP and the recursive iterator class.  Thanks for all the support.

I found a youtube video that helped linked below
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jtqVJ3-95m4